# breakpoint saas gem not generating correct css output

Tags: sass, breakpoint-sass

I'm not sure if this is on my end, or a legitimate bug. But when I do something like this:

```
@include breakpoint(0px 1000px) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

the CSS that gets generated is:

```
@media screen and (0px: 1000px) {
```

Shouldn't it be something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1000px)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2.0, breakpoint 2.0.7

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include @import "breakpoint"; 
at the top of my file. Even though it was included elsewhere, I had to actually put it in each  file that I was using..